# Pymongo Update field with DateTimeField

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to update one field with the DatetimeField where field value is None. My query for the same is.

```
db.collection.update_many({"field":None},{"$set":{"field":"$date"}})
```

My update result is date:"$date" but the date field is of type datetime how to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Put a date in the field `date` ?

Comment: "field" is other column and i am trying to copy date value to field

Comment: create a `datetime` object and replace `"$date"` with `datetime` object

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": {
                "field":None
            } 
        },
        { "$addFields": { 
            "field": "$date"
        }},
        { "$out": "Timeslot" }
    ]
)
```

Comment: It is not updating the field column

Comment: In the `$out` stage,  you have to put the name of your collection. Mine was `Timeslot`